# Shiro warning thrown when attaching CredentialMatcher to iniRealm

Tags: java, shiro

I've got an issue regarding Shiro iniRealm and CredentialMatcher. I'm creating a securityManager with an ini file. In that Ini file, in the main section, I'm putting that :

```
main.put("NellMatcher","com.nellarmonia.shuttle.security.shiro.NellCredentialMatcher");
main.put("iniRealm.credentialsMatcher", "$NellMatcher");
```

My full Ini has two sections:

- One users containing lots of users
- One main containing three entries:

> NellMatcher =>
>   com.nellarmonia.shuttle.security.shiro.NellCredentialMatcher 
>   iniRealm.credentialsMatcher => $NellMatcher
>       securityManager.subjectDAO.sessionStorageEvaluator.sessionStorageEnabled
>   => false

This should be good according to https://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#credentials-matching.

I'm trying to attach my own credential matcher to the default iniRealm.Then I do :

```
 Factory factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory(ini);      
    securityManager = factory.getInstance();
```

and this warning is thrown :

```
org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm - Users or Roles are already populated.
Configured Ini instance will be ignored.
```

If I did a little bit in the source code, I can see that in `buildObjects` method of `ReflectionBuilder.java`, we
first process the kvPairs and then initialize the objects with :

```
//SHIRO-413:init method must be called for constructed objects that are Initializable      
LifecycleUtils.init(objects.values());
```

But in the execute method of `BeanConfigurationProcessor`, the iniRealm is also initialized because the Pair `"iniRealm.credentialsMatcher", "$NellMatcher"` is being processed.

Therefore, iniRealm is initialized and the call to "
`LifecycleUtils.init(objects.values());`" tries to re-init the iniRealm again,
thus throwing the warning.

Is this a bug or am I missing something ?

Comment: What does your full `Ini` object look like?

Comment: I've edited the description :)